# Access Firestore database not the Realtime database using Javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

If I use: `firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)` and pass it the 6 key value pairs it defaults to using the Realtime database to store data but I need it to use Firestore.  How can I change this.  Thanks.

Comment: [Quickstart to setup firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart)

Comment: Defaults to Real Time? Are you calling database() instead of firestore()?